# Tizen - Hello World on Samsung Gear Live

Tags: android, wear-os, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am trying to load a test app onto my Samsung Gear Live. In Tizen when I try to "Run As->Tizen Wearable Web Application" I get the message that says, "There is no target to launch. Please select an emulator or a device in Connection Explorer."

I don't see where to select a physical device in the connection explorer.

I have turned on ADB debugging via USB. I am able to see the device with ADB. I am ***not*** able to with SDB.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? I have been searching for hours, and can't seem to find the documentation that I need :(

Thanks.

Comment: Samsung Gear Live runs on Android Wear OS and it doesn't have any relation with Tizen OS. Other Samsung Gear wearables are based on Tizen, but Samsung Gear Live does not.

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I was looking for. If you submit it as the answer I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other Samsung Gear wearables like:

- **Galaxy Gear** (after being updated to **Tizen**, originally runs on modified Android)
- **Gear 2**
- **Gear 2 Neo**
- **Gear S**

are based on **Tizen** OS, but **Samsung Gear Live** does not. It runs on **Android Wear** OS and it doesn't have any relation with **Tizen** OS.

**Note:** For the full view of Samsung's wearables it's good to mention that **Gear Fit** doesn't run **Android** or **Tizen**, but some lighter OS instead.
Thanks to @VykthurD. who noticed it in the comment below and corrected me:)

Comment: Excellent answer ...
Just a slight correction, the Gear Fit, runs a different, lighter OS (not tizen) .
http://www.cnet.com/news/samsungs-gear-fit-doesnt-run-android-or-tizen/

Comment: @VykthurD. Thanks! I have edited my answer and removed Gear Fit to not misinform people:)